# Как сделать автоматическую высоту блока для элементов с position: absolute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста решить одну задачку

Есть допустим такой код

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  top: 0;
  left: +150px;
}

ul.menu-parent {
  display: block;
  position: static;
  left: 0;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="menu-parent">
    <li>
      123
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      234
      <ul>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>6</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      345
      <ul>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Как реализовать, что бы родительский div подстраивался под все елементы меню и выпадающие списки? Возможно ли решить без применения js?

Comment: Без JS вряд ли получится: абсолютно позиционированные элементы не влияют на размер родителя. А другого способа так расположить подменю наверное и нет. Можно сделать подменю статичным и по hover-у менять ему высоту.

Comment: @Геннадий Журов Припоминаю, когда-то видел как елемент чисто на css подстраивался под меню, но не помню как именно это реализовывалось, и не могу найти ничего подобного( Возможно флоатами как-то реализовывалось